# (MVC) LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'Boolean VerifyHashedPassword(Byte[], System.String)' method

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

When I run my code and there is an error occur over here.Can anyone help me on this? I am new in MVC. Thank you.

```html
public ActionResult Login(AspNetUser user)
        {
            using (eMediCareDBEntities db = new eMediCareDBEntities())
            {
                //byte[] temp = Convert.FromBase64String("AEh/kUSTE019aDWRoSscnT0c/XArWnjMyBeIgQ1MgTAqRetiD84KgdkFAgHO/bfFKQ==");

                //bool result = VerifyHashedPassword(temp, user.PasswordHash);

                var v = db.AspNetUsers.Single(a => a.UserName.Equals(user.UserName) && VerifyHashedPassword(Convert.FromBase64String(a.PasswordHash), user.PasswordHash) == true);
                if(v != null)
                {
                    Session["Id"] = v.Id.ToString();
                    Session["UserName"] = v.UserName.ToString();
                    return RedirectToAction("Main");
                }
                else
                {
                    ModelState.AddModelError("", "Username or Password is wrong.");
                }
            }
            return View();
        }
```

The error is:

> An exception of type 'System.NotSupportedException' occurred in EntityFramework.SqlServer.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method `Boolean VerifyHashedPassword(Byte[], System.String)` method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.

Error occur at:

```
var v = db.AspNetUsers.Single(a => a.UserName.Equals(user.UserName) && VerifyHashedPassword(Convert.FromBase64String(a.PasswordHash), user.PasswordHash) == true);
```

Comment: You can convert the AspNetUsers into a list and then apply your filtering logic var v = db.AspNetUsers.ToList().Single(a => a.UserName.Equals(user.UserName)) && VerifyHashedPassword(Convert.FromBase64String(a.PasswordHash), user.PasswordHash) == true);

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Linq2Entities tries to translate your expression to SQL. Custom C# code like `VerifyHashedPassword` can not be translated.

As a work around, execute the Linq query first, then apply your custom code in-memory.

```
var matchingUsers = db.AspNetUsers.Single(a => a.UserName).ToArray(); // enumerating the query will execute it

var v = matchingUsers.SingleOrDefault(a => VerifyHashedPassword(Convert.FromBase64String(a.PasswordHash), user.PasswordHash) == true);
```

Comment: get it. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

That is because you are limited in what you can write in expression here

```
var v = db.AspNetUsers.Single(a => a.UserName.Equals(user.UserName) && VerifyHashedPassword(Convert.FromBase64String(a.PasswordHash), user.PasswordHash) == true);
```

and in addition, better to use FirstOrDefault in your case and comparing bool value to true doesn't really make sense.
I would recommend to rewrite your code as

```
public ActionResult Login(AspNetUser user)
        {
            using (eMediCareDBEntities db = new eMediCareDBEntities())
            {
                //byte[] temp = Convert.FromBase64String("AEh/kUSTE019aDWRoSscnT0c/XArWnjMyBeIgQ1MgTAqRetiD84KgdkFAgHO/bfFKQ==");

                //bool result = VerifyHashedPassword(temp, user.PasswordHash);

                var v = db.AspNetUsers.FirstOrDefault(a => a.UserName == user.UserName);
                if(v != null &&  v.VerifyHashedPassword(Convert.FromBase64String(a.PasswordHash), user.PasswordHash))
                {
                    Session["Id"] = v.Id.ToString();
                    Session["UserName"] = v.UserName.ToString();
                    return RedirectToAction("Main");
                }
                else
                {
                    ModelState.AddModelError("", "Username or Password is wrong.");
                }
            }
            return View();
        }
```

Comment: get it. Thank you.